# Is there a way to call a function through using a string that matches its name?

Tags: javascript

This is what I have attempted, and may give a better gist of the question I'm trying to ask:

```
var x = "run";
var y = "Function";
var xy = x + y;

function runFunction() {
    console.log("Function has been called.");
}

xy();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you're basically doing this `'runFunction'()`
And that's not how you call a function.

Comment: xy is not a function

Comment: In practice, you never need — or _want_, really — dynamic variable names. Use a simple object instead: `const obj = { runFunction(){`…`} };` … `obj[x + y]();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `eval()`, but **don't**. Instead, store your functions in an object:

```
const functions = {
  greetingOne: () => console.log("Hello!"),
  anotherGreeting: () => console.log("Hi there!");
};

const f = "greetingOne";
functions[f]();
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if the function lives on an object.

```
const obj = {
  runFunction: function() {console.log('hello')}
}

var x = "run";
var y = "Function";
var xy = x + y;

obj[xy]();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `eval` that run string as Javascript code

```
function runFunction() {
    console.log("Function has been called.");
}
functionName = 'runFunction'
eval(functionName + '()');
```

Answer (score 0):

All global functions stores in window object.

```js
let first = "first";
let second = "Second";

let xy = first+second;

function firstSecond() {
    return "Hello World";
}


console.log(window[xy]());
```

Comment: this is only valid for javascript in a browser